# Modify date header in PHP email?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Is it possible to manipulate the date header using PHP's mail function/sendmail (website server is linux so I believe it's using sendmail underneath)?

I'm trying to test error handling of a (windows based) email checker, and need to generate an invalid date header in a message, but when I send my message using php mail, even though I am including a custom Date header, it seems to get overridden by the mail server and my custom header ignored. I'm guessing I might need an additional parameter for sendmail to tamper with that header, but I can't seem to find what that parameter would be, or whether this is even possible.

Here is what I am sending (with the personal domain info removed)

```
$headers = "From: ..................\r\n";
$headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@..................>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
//$headers .= "Date: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\n"; //a valid header for comparison
$headers .= "Date: Tuesday\n"; // intentionally bogus email header
$headers .= "Reply-To: ..................\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ..................\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\nX-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "\n";
$success=mail($to, $s_subject, $s_emailmsg, $headers);
```

Comment: You might be better off directly connecting to the SMTP port and initiating the email yourself, giving you total control over the process.

Comment: I agree with Marc, certainly for just some tests, SMTP is quite a simple protocol and not that hard to talk to another server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wrote an email checker that runs via `procmail`, an easier way might be to construct an email message yourself and send that directly to the test script via standard input.

It's easier to write unit tests that way as it bypasses any interference by other mail servers. When you do follow this, make sure that the first line starts with `MAIL FROM xx@yy.com`.

Comment: unfortunately, my email checker application is a windows application, so this probably won't work for me, though I like your strategy and it sounds like an interesting way to solve similar sorts of problems.